# View all installed libraries and how they are to be imported in Coq

Tags: coq

I've been wanting to use [coq-vpl](https://github.com/VERIMAG-Polyhedra/VPL/blob/master/README.md), and I have it installed. I can confirm this from `opam list`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ opam list
# Installed packages for system:
...
coq                    8.6  Formal proof management system.
coq-vpl                0.2  Coq interface to VPL abstract domain of convex polyhedra.
coq-vpltactic          0.2  A Coq Tactic for Arithmetic (based on VPL).
coqide                 8.6  IDE of the Coq formal proof management system.
...
```

However, how do I find out what the library is actually called and what I need to import? The `vpl` page does not have docs on it.

Comment: You can find some info on GitHub: [VplTactic](https://github.com/VERIMAG-Polyhedra/VplTactic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run

```
coqc -config
```

To get a list of configuration variables.  On my system, this gives

```
LOCAL=0
COQLIB=/home/jgross/.local64/coq/coq-8.7.1/lib/coq/
DOCDIR=/home/jgross/.local64/coq/coq-8.7.1/share/doc/coq/
OCAMLFIND=/home/jgross/.opam/system/bin/ocamlfind
CAMLP4=camlp5
CAMLP4O=/home/jgross/.opam/system/bin/camlp5o
CAMLP4BIN=/home/jgross/.opam/4.02.2/bin/
CAMLP4LIB=/home/jgross/.opam/system/lib/camlp5
CAMLP4OPTIONS=-loc loc
CAMLFLAGS=-thread -rectypes -w +a-4-9-27-41-42-44-45-48-50 -bin-annot -safe-string
HASNATDYNLINK=true
COQ_SRC_SUBDIRS=config dev lib kernel library engine pretyping interp parsing proofs tactics toplevel printing intf grammar ide stm vernac plugins/btauto plugins/cc plugins/derive plugins/extraction plugins/firstorder plugins/fourier plugins/funind plugins/ltac plugins/micromega plugins/nsatz plugins/omega plugins/quote plugins/romega plugins/rtauto plugins/setoid_ring plugins/ssr plugins/ssrmatching plugins/syntax plugins/xml
```

If you look at the `user-contrib` directory of the path given by `COQLIB`, you should see folders with the various libraries you've installed.  For any of these folder names, you can add `From FolderName Require Import FileName` to your Coq file.

Comment: Thank you, this is a wonderful answer that is of a "learn how to learn" flavour :)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/VERIMAG-Polyhedra/VplTactic, you need to run coq, for instance by launching `coqide` (which you installed) and by typing the following lines in the left-hand-side window and executing them (using the downward green arrows on top of the window).

```
Require Import VplTactic.Tactic.
Add Field Qcfield: Qcft (decidable Qc_eq_bool_correct, constants [vpl_cte]).
```

And so on, please read the page at the link given above.  I did not try it yet.

Comment: Indeed, but that is their tactic, and not the library. The tactic implements a decision procedure using their library